# How to display sending messages on right side and receiving messages on left side?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on chat application.Here I am able to send and receive the messages.But i want to display the sending messages on right side and receiving messages on left

```js
var grp = angular.module("grpApp", [])
    .controller("grpCtrl", function ($scope, $state, $http, $stateParams) {
        $scope.uName = $state.params.usermail;
        console.log("bigid" + " " + $scope.digId);
        document.getElementById("frndName").innerHTML = "Group";
        $scope.message = '';
        $scope.messages = [];

        /*...............................image upload......................................*/
        $("#profileImage").click(function (e) {
            $("#imageUpload").click();
        });

        function fasterPreview(uploader) {
            if (uploader.files && uploader.files[0]) {
                $('#profileImage').attr('src',
                    window.URL.createObjectURL(uploader.files[0]));
            }
        }

        $("#imageUpload").change(function () {
            fasterPreview(this);
        });
        /*...............................image upload end................................*/
        var socket = io('http://colourssoftware.com:3000/chat');
        console.log("socket" + socket);
        console.log("devi" + socket);
        var username = $scope.uName;
        var noChat = 0; //setting 0 if all chats histroy is not loaded. 1 if all chats loaded.
        var msgCount = 0; //counting total number of messages displayed.
        var oldInitDone = 0; //it is 0 when old-chats-init is not executed and 1 if executed.
        var roomId; //variable for setting room.
        var toUser;

        //passing data on connection.
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            socket.emit('set-user-data', $scope.uName);
            console.log("emitted" + $scope.uName);
        }); //end of connect event.

        //receiving onlineStack.
        socket.on('onlineStack', function (stack) {
            $('#list').empty();
            $('#list').append($('<li>').append($('<button id="ubtn" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-sm"></button>').text("Group").css({
                "font-size": "13px"
            })));
            var totalOnline = 0;
            for (var user in stack) {
                //setting txt1. shows users button.
                if (user == $scope.uName) {
                    var txt1 = $('<span></span>').text(user).css({
                        "font-size": "13px"
                    });
                } else {
                    var txt1 = $('<span id="ubtn"></span>').text(user).css({
                        "font-size": "13px"
                    });
                }
                //setting txt2. shows online status.
                if (stack[user] == "Online") {
                    var txt2 = $('<span></span>').text("*" + stack[user]).css({
                        "float": "right",
                        "color": "#009933",
                        "font-size": "13px"
                    });
                    totalOnline++;
                } else {
                    var txt2 = $('<span></span>').text(stack[user]).css({
                        "float": "right",
                        "color": "#a6a6a6",
                        "font-size": "13px"
                    });
                }
                //listing all users.
                $('#list').append($('<li>').append(txt1, txt2));
                $('#totalOnline').text(totalOnline);
            } //end of for.
            $('#scrl1').scrollTop($('#scrl1').prop("scrollHeight"));
        }); //end of receiving onlineStack event.


        //on button click function.
        $(document).on("click", "#ubtn", function () {


            //                    $scope.toUser = touser;
            console.log("username" + toUser);
            //empty messages.
            $('#messages').empty();
            $('#typing').text("");
            msgCount = 0;
            noChat = 0;
            oldInitDone = 0;

            //assigning friends name to whom messages will send,(in case of group its value is Group).
            toUser = $(this).text();

            //showing and hiding relevant information.
            $('#frndName').text(toUser);
            $('#initMsg').hide();
            $('#chatForm').show(); //showing chat form.
            $('#sendBtn').hide(); //hiding send button to prevent sending of empty messages.

            //assigning two names for room. which helps in one-to-one and also group chat.
            if (toUser == "Group") {
                var currentRoom = "Group-Group";
                var reverseRoom = "Group-Group";
            } else {
                var currentRoom = username + "-" + toUser;
                var reverseRoom = toUser + "-" + username;
            }

            //event to set room and join.
            socket.emit('set-room', {
                name1: currentRoom,
                name2: reverseRoom
            });
            console.log("room" + currentRoom + " " + reverseRoom);
        });
        //event for setting roomId.
        socket.on('set-room', function (room) {
            //empty messages.
            $('#messages').empty();
            $('#typing').text("");
            msgCount = 0;
            noChat = 0;
            oldInitDone = 0;
            //assigning room id to roomId variable. which helps in one-to-one and group chat.
            roomId = room;
            console.log("roomId : " + roomId);
            //event to get chat history on button click or as room is set.
            socket.emit('old-chats-init', {
                room: roomId,
                username: $scope.uName,
                msgCount: msgCount
            });
            $scope.deleteCht = function () {
                $http({
                    url: 'http://colourssoftware.com:3000/clearchat/' + roomId,
                    method: 'DELETE',
                }).then(function (res) {
                    //document.getElementById("scrl2").value = "";
                    //data.result.length = 0;
                    console.log("del chat " + JSON.stringify(res.data));
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log("errorblock" + error);
                });

            }


        }); //end of set-room event.





        //on scroll load more old-chats.
        $('#scrl2').scroll(function () {

            if ($('#scrl2').scrollTop() == 0 && noChat == 0 && oldInitDone == 1) {
                $('#loading').show();
                socket.emit('old-chats', {
                    room: roomId,
                    username: username,
                    msgCount: msgCount
                });
            }

        }); // end of scroll event.

        //listening old-chats event.
        socket.on('old-chats', function (data) {

            if (data.room == roomId) {
                console.log("name" + JSON.stringify(data));
                oldInitDone = 1; //setting value to implies that old-chats first event is done.
                if (data.result.length != 0) {
                    $('#noChat').hide(); //hiding no more chats message.
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
                        //styling of chat message.
                        var chatDate = moment(data.result[i].createdOn).format("MMMM Do YYYY, hh:mm:ss a");
                        var txt1 = $('<span></span>').text(data.result[i].msgFrom + " : ").css({
                            "color": "#006080"
                        });
                        var txt2 = $('<span></span>').text(chatDate).css({
                            "float": "right",
                            "color": "#a6a6a6",
                            "font-size": "16px"
                        });
                        var txt3 = $('<p></p>').append(txt1, txt2);
                        var txt4 = $('<p></p>').text(data.result[i].msg).css({
                            "color": "#000000"
                        });
                        //showing chat in chat box.
                        $('#messages').prepend($('<li>').append(txt3, txt4));
                        msgCount++;

                    } //end of for.
                    console.log(msgCount);
                } else {
                    $('#noChat').show(); //displaying no more chats message.
                    noChat = 1; //to prevent unnecessary scroll event.
                    console.log("devi");
                }
                //hiding loading bar.
                $('#loading').hide();

                //setting scrollbar position while first 5 chats loads.
                if (msgCount <= 5) {
                    $('#scrl2').scrollTop($('#scrl2').prop("scrollHeight"));
                }
            } //end of outer if.

        }); // end of listening old-chats event.

        // keyup handler.
        $('#myMsg').keyup(function () {
            if ($('#myMsg').val()) {
                $('#sendBtn').show(); //showing send button.
                socket.emit('typing');
            } else {
                $('#sendBtn').hide(); //hiding send button to prevent sending empty messages.
            }
        }); //end of keyup handler.

        //receiving typing message.
        socket.on('typing', function (msg) {
            var setTime;
            //clearing previous setTimeout function.
            clearTimeout(setTime);
            //showing typing message.
            $('#typing').text(msg);
            //showing typing message only for few seconds.
            setTime = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#typing').text("");
            }, 3000);
        }); //end of typing event.

        //sending message.

        $('form').submit(function () {
            socket.emit('chat-msg', {
                msg: $('#myMsg').val(),
                msgTo: toUser,
                date: Date.now()
            });
            console.log("date" + Date.now());
            $('#myMsg').val("");
            $('#sendBtn').hide();
            return false;
        });

        //end of sending message.

        //receiving messages.
        socket.on('chat-msg', function (data) {
            //styling of chat message.
            var chatDate = moment(data.date).format("MMMM Do YYYY, hh:mm:ss a");
            var txt1 = $('<span></span>').text(data.msgFrom + " : ").css({
                "color": "#006080"
            });
            var txt2 = $('<span></span>').text(chatDate).css({
                "float": "right",
                "color": "#a6a6a6",
                "font-size": "13px"
            });
            var txt3 = $('<p ></p>').append(txt1, txt2);
            var txt4 = $('<p></p>').text(data.msg).css({
                "color": "#000000"
            });
            //showing chat in chat box.
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').append(txt3, txt4));
            msgCount = msgCount + 1;
            console.log(msgCount);
            $('#typing').text("");
            $('#scrl2').scrollTop($('#scrl2').prop("scrollHeight"));
        }); //end of receiving messages.


        //on disconnect event.
        //passing data on connection.
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            //showing and hiding relevant information.
            $('#list').empty();
            $('#messages').empty();
            $('#typing').text("");
            $('#frndName').text("Disconnected..");
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#noChat').hide();
            $('#initMsg').show().text("...Please, Refresh Your Page...");
            $('#chatForm').hide();
            msgCount = 0;
            noChat = 0;
        }); //end of connect event.


        //end of function.
        /*...................................socket...................................................*/








        /*  $http.get("http://colourssoftware.com:3000/friendrequests/" + $scope.uName)
                .then(function (response) {

                    $scope.seefrnds = response.data;
                    console.log("response" + "   " + JSON.stringify(response.data));
                    $scope.reqName = response.requestname;



                    //console.log("array print" + JSON.stringify($scope.usersList));
                }, function (response) {
                    console.log("response");
                });
*/

        /*FRIEND REQUESTS*/
        //$scope.userName = $state.params.usermail;
        console.log("username:" + $scope.uName);
        $scope.userId = $state.params.userid;

        $scope.msgFrm = $state.params.usermail;
        $scope.uid = $state.params.user;
        $scope.frndN;
        $scope.msgdata = [];
        $scope.frndData = [];



        var frndata = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://colourssoftware.com:3000/userslist',
            }
            //document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Group";

        $scope.usersList = [];
        $scope.friendsList = [];





        var d = new Date();
        $scope.time = d.toLocaleString();
        console.log("hlooo" + $scope.time);

        /*document.getElementById("myMsg").addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("sendBtn").click();
    }
});*/
        /*getting all the friends accepted by me and who accepts me*/
        $scope.acceptedFrnds = [];
        $scope.getFrnds = function () {

            $http.get("http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Accept_Requests/" + $scope.uid)
                .then(function (response) {
                        console.log("acceptedlist" + JSON.stringify(response));
                        $scope.acceptedFrnds = response.data;
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        console.log("error");

                    });
            $http.get("http://colourssoftware.com:3000/Accepted_By_Others/" + $scope.msgFrm)
                .then(function (response) {
                        console.log("acceptedbyothers" + JSON.stringify(response));
                        $scope.acceptedFrnds = response.data;
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        console.log("error");
                    });

        }
        $scope.fgrp = function (name) {
            document.getElementById("frndName").innerHTML = name;


        }


        $scope.frndgrp = function (frnd) {
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = frnd;
            $scope.msgdata = [];
            $scope.frndN = frnd;
            console.log("frndnnnnn" + $scope.frndN);

        }
        console.log("hiauhdurhk" + $scope.frndN);
        /*sending chat messages*/
        $scope.send = function () {
            $scope.msgdata = [];
            //console.log("shgsd" + frnds);
            document.getElementById("submitmsg").disabled = false;

            $scope.msgdata.push($scope.message + " " + " " + $scope.time);



            /*posting the chat messages*/
            var data = {
                "msgFrom": $scope.msgFrm,

                "msgTo": $scope.frndN,
                "msg": $scope.msgdata,
                "room": $scope.msgFrm
            };
            console.log(data);


            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://colourssoftware.com:3000/chatroute',
                data: data
            }
            $http(req).then(function (response) {
                console.log("hjhuhjh" + JSON.stringify(response.data));
                $scope.msgdata = "";
                $scope.displayFun();

            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
            $scope.displayFun = function () {
                    $http.get("http://colourssoftware.com:3000/chathistory")
                        .then(function (response) {

                            $scope.msgdata = response.data;

                            console.log("array print" + JSON.stringify($scope.msgdata));
                        }, function (response) {
                            console.log("error block");


                            // $window.sessionStorage.setItem("Mydata", JSON.stringify($scope.usersList));
                        });
                }
                //            $http.get("http://192.168.2.48:3000/chathistory")
                //        .then(function (response) {
                //
                //            $scope.msgdata = response.data;
                //
                //            console.log("array print" + JSON.stringify($scope.msgdata));
                //        
                //           // $window.sessionStorage.setItem("Mydata", JSON.stringify($scope.usersList));
                //        });

            //$scope.msgdata = "";

        }
        $scope.showGrp = function () {
            document.getElementById("frndName").innerHTML = "Group";
            $scope.msgdata = [];
            // var retData = localStorage.getItem("storedData");
            // var retrieveData = JSON.parse(retData);
            //console.log("heloooo" + retrieveData);
            // $scope.msgdata.push(retrieveData);
        }

        $scope.deleteFrnd = function (Id) {
            // $scope.seefrnds.splice(index, 1);
            $scope.Id = Id;
            console.log("show id" + Id);
            $http({
                url: 'http://colourssoftware.com:3000/deletefriends/' + $scope.Id,
                method: 'DELETE',
                data: {
                    id: $scope.Id
                },
                //                headers: {
                //                    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
                //                }
            }).then(function (res) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data));

            }, function (error) {
                console.log("errorblock" + error);
            });

        }



    });
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <input type="hidden" id="user" value="<%= user.username %>" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" style="height:500px;overflow: scroll">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="images.jpg" width="80px" height="80px" style="float:left">
                            <span>{{uName}}</span>
                            <h5></h5>
                        </div>
                        <!--model------------------------------------------------------------------->
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header" id="profile-container">
                                        <img class=" img-circle " src="images.jpg" width="80px" height="80px" align='center' id="profileImage">


                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                                    </div>
                                    <input id="imageUpload" type="file" name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture align="center" ng-hide=true>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                                        <p ng-bind="uName"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--------------------------------------------------- model close------------------------------------->
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." class="search focus" id="Searchtab1">
                        <h4>Friends</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body list-group" id="scrl1">
                        <ul id="list" style="cursor: pointer" class="list-group list-group-item"></ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="panel-footer">
                        <p id="typing"></p>
                    </div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=".space"></div>
            <div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <!--<script>
    document.div.style.backgroundImage = url("p.jpg");
</script>-->
                    <div class="panel panel-primary" style="height:500px;overflow: scroll">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 id="frndName" align="center">Chat Room</h4>
                            <span id="typing"></span>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="float:right;margin-top:-4%" ng-click="deleteCht()" title="clear chat"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body" id="scrl2">
                            <p id="loading">Loading.....</p>
                            <p id="noChat">No More Chats To Display.....</p>
                            <p id="initMsg">!!...Click On User Or Group Button To Start Chat...!!</p>
                            <ul id="messages"></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer input-group" style="width:100%">

                            <form id="chatForm" action="" onsubmit="return false">
                                <input id="myMsg" class="input-box-send  form-control" ng-model="message" autocomplete="off" style="width:90%" placeholder="Write Message Here.." />
                                <button type="submit" id="sendBtn" class=" btn btn-primary " style="width:10%" ng-disabled="!message" name="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

side.how can I meet that requirement?
Here I am attaching my code.

Comment: Is this your whole application? Please post just the relevant code or create a working plunker/fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of:

- `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on parent
- `align-self: flex-end`on children

everything should be really easy to achieve.

```css
.chat {
  display: flex;
  
  /* column reverse to have chat-style message ordering*/
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.message {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 60%;
}

.message.is-sent {
  background: cyan;
  
  /* use align-self */
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.message.is-received {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">

<div class="message is-received">
 Received - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus corporis delectus in mollitia nulla numquam perferendis, porro provident sint ullam! A eos ipsum maiores quisquam vero? Enim nihil quisquam rerum.
</div>

<div class="message is-sent">
 Sent - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus corporis delectus in mollitia nulla numquam perferendis, porro provident sint ullam! A eos ipsum maiores quisquam vero? Enim nihil quisquam rerum.
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just create two classes for right and left aligned blocks. And when you show this add classes to messages. E.g. for messages you sent `item--left-align`.
However, you have to not forget about pseudo elements

```
.item--left-align {
  float: left;
}

.item--left-align:after,
.item--left-align:before {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

You need it for control on elements that will change their position caused by `float`